# Flutter hot reload is not working. help needed

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter hot reload is not working with intelliJ/ Android studio.

[image: Buttons]

Once I run the app on my Poco F1 which run Android Q and is rooted, the app runs on the device but I cannot rerun the app or hot reload it, I have to stop and build again.

I am able to get the logs from the app, so there is no problem of connectivity.

Things I've tried:

1. Flutter clean
2. Increased Logger Buffer Size
3. Tried Emulator with Android Q
4. Tried Emulator with Android P
5. Tried device with Android P
6. Changing channels

Following is my flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\tools\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (8 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ghost\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.2
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.6015.53

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • POCO F1 • 50c8824d • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!
```

If I do Flutter run:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on POCO F1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         6.5s
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity(29390): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29390): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29390): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29390): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView(29390): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@cdd7e8a
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(29390): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  shared_preferences:
  google_fonts:
```

So even if I close the app on device, main.dart doesn't stop.

Any Idea what's causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Update plugins and dart too. Sometimes even a system reboot also does the job

Comment: could you show your main.dart code

Comment: @AshokKumar You can find it here: https://pastebin.com/kTSvEaj0

Comment: try removing future stuff and make simple call as : void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Comment: @AshokKumar Doesn't wok even then

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue before. I faced the issue with the older flutter versions. Run following commands

```
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
```

Now try to run the app and check the hot reload.

Comment: Didn't work,  Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-IN)